# Schedule setup string without using CRON string

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Currently we are using cron strings for setting Quartz jobs in our project. But it seems to be either overkill or little confusing to set by a admin guy who is not a developer. So, we try to use a simple string like this,

```
each 1 seconds on MonTueWedThuFri between 00:01 and 23:59
```

Is there any existing frameworks (or in Quartz) I will be able to get a cron string out of this string? (I know i can parse this to get a simple trigger, but don't want to DRY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such implementation yet, I would like to contribute a Contrib (or a patch) once I am done with it. I am currently writing this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't one as far as I know. Your example wouldn't work just SimpleTrigger, you would also need a calendar to get rid of firing in the weekend. So in this case CronTrigger would probable be the thing you are looking for.

But back to the original question... There probably isn't any made for Quartz(.NET) and it would quite fast prove itself to be non-trivial.